# How to use Log4j2 in a JAX-WS Java Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, configuration, jax-ws, log4j2

As documented in a [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059153/cannot-run-jax-ws-java-web-service-on-apache-tomcat), I am learning how to use **JAX-WS (Java API for XML Web Services)**.  I've used [Log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) in previous executable Java programs, and I'd like to use it for logging web service requests.  How can I add **Log4j2** to the base code in [this JAX-WS tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I solved this question:

#### Procedure

1. Download the latest Log4j2 libraries from [the Apache project site](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html).
2. Unzip the Log4j2 compressed folder, and copy the following files to the project's `lib` folder.

   - **log4j-api-2.3.jar**
   - **log4j-core-2.3.jar**
3. If you wish the log to be emailed, you will also need to copy the following files to the project's `lib` folder:

   - **log4j-web-2.3.jar**
   - **javax.mail.jar** (which may be downloaded [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home))
4. Be sure to set a reference to the copied JAR files in the Netbeans project:
   [image: screenshot of added references]
5. Add a file named **log4j2.xml** to the `Source Packages` folder (see screenshot above).  The contents of my log4j2.xml file are below to use as a starting point.

   - Notice that I intentionally place the log file in the `{$Tomcat}\logs` folder.  I originally had placed the application's log file in the `{$Tomcat}\webapps\HelloWorld` folder.  However, I learned that Tomcat keeps file locks on the log files that will prevent "hot deploy/undeploy", leading to an incomplete deployment and a web application that doesn't work.  For more info, search for **antiResourceLocking** on this [page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

> ```
> <Configuration status='off'>
>     <Properties>
>         <Property name='logFilePath'>logs/HelloWorld.log</Property>
>     </Properties>
>     <Appenders>
>         <Console name='Console' target='SYSTEM_OUT'>
>             <PatternLayout pattern='%m%n'/>
>         </Console>
>         <File name='File' fileName='${logFilePath}'>
>             <PatternLayout>
>                 <Pattern>%d %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
>             </PatternLayout>
>         </File>
>         <SMTP name='Email' subject='JAX-WS Hello World Tutorial Web Service' to='matthew.pfluger@plexus.com' from='noreply-AgileUserManager@plexus.com'
>               smtpHost='intranet-smtp.plexus.com' smtpPort='25' bufferSize='10000'>
>             <PatternLayout>
>                 <Header>One or more errors occurred!  Please see the full log file at: ${logFilePath}.%n</Header>
>                 <Pattern>%d %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
>             </PatternLayout>
>         </SMTP>
>     </Appenders>
>     <Loggers>
>         <Root level='debug'>
>             <AppenderRef ref='File'/>
>             <AppenderRef ref='Console'/>
>             <AppenderRef ref='Email'/>
>         </Root>
>     </Loggers>
> </Configuration>
> ```

6. In the **web.xml** file, add the following snippet:

> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
>     <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

7. Now all the setup is complete, so it's time to add some logging!  You're free to add your own logging steps, but here is how I modified the `HelloWorldImpl.java` file.

   - Notice that I'm intentionally logging and throwing an Exception.  I'm doing this because I'm testing my `log4j2.xml` configuration to make sure an email is sent when an Exception is logged.

> ```
> package com.mkyong.ws;
>
> import javax.jws.WebService;
> import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
> import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
>
> @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld")
> public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
>
>     private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorldImpl.class);
>
>     @Override
>     public String getHelloWorldAsString() throws Exception {
>         logger.entry();
>         logger.info("Request received");
>         logger.exit();
>
>         final Exception exception = new Exception("What the heck happened?");
>         logger.error(exception);
>         throw exception;
>     }
> }
> ```

8. Finally, compile the application to a WAR file and deploy to your Tomcat server.  Then, after submitting a request to the service, the application will now perform logging.

I hope this is helpful! - Pflugs

#### References

- [how to configure log4j2 webapplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349008/how-to-configure-log4j2-webapplication) (particularly for which JAR files to include in the WEB-INF/lib)
- [Using Log4j 2 in Web Applications](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) (Apache documentation)
- [Log4j2 SMTPAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) (in case you wish to email errors from the log)
- [Tomcat Context Container Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) (helped me understand why Tomcat was keeping a lock on the log files)